# TeamCity API work out how long investigation took to start?

Tags: teamcity

Using the TeamCity API:

We are trying to put together a dashboard to work out how long from a build failing, it took for someone to assign themselves to an investigation for the build / project.

We cant find a way to do this as investigations are assigned to projects not builds so there is no way to find out when an investigation started for a particular build ?

Comment: What version of TeamCity do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get investigation for build configuration you may use the following REST API:

http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/investigations?locator=buildType:(id:XXXX)

For example, the following request
https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/rest/investigations?locator=buildType:(id:Epigenome_GenestackTests)

returns the following response, which has **timestamp** under **assignment** node:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<investigations count="1" href="/app/rest/investigations?locator=buildType:(id:Epigenome_GenestackTests)">
   <investigation id="buildType:(id:Epigenome_GenestackTests)" state="TAKEN" href="/app/rest/investigations/buildType:(id:Epigenome_GenestackTests)">
      <assignee username="evgeny.kurbatsky" name="Evgeny.Kurbatsky" id="1107" href="/app/rest/users/id:1107" />
      <assignment>
         <user username="oleg" name="Oleg Shpynov" id="2" href="/app/rest/users/id:2" />
         <timestamp>20160321T122158+0000</timestamp>
      </assignment>
      <scope>
         <buildTypes count="1">
            <buildType id="Epigenome_GenestackTests" name="Genestack Tests" paused="true" description="Fast tests" projectName="BioLabs :: Epigenome" projectId="Epigenome" href="/app/rest/buildTypes/id:Epigenome_GenestackTests" webUrl="https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=Epigenome_GenestackTests" />
         </buildTypes>
      </scope>
      <target anyProblem="true" />
      <resolution type="whenFixed" />
   </investigation>
</investigations>
```